# Export a List of Functions With Rollup.js - ECMA6 Modules

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, export, rollupjs

I am using Rollup.js to put together a module from a larger number of individual JS sources. Each file contains an individual object with the exception of `util.js` which, as the name suggests, contains a bunch of various helper functions and goodies = multiple exports.

I wish to export these functions with my module, but simply doing:

```
export * from './util';
```

puts all the functions directly in the main scope. I'd like to export those functions in a sub-object so instead of:

```
module.function1
module.function2
...
```

I'd get:

```
module.util.function1
module.util.function2
...
```

I know I could just import all the functions, make the object myself and then export it:

```
import { ... } from './util';
export const util =
{
    function1 : function1,
    function2 : function2,
    ...
};
```

But it feels kinda silly to write the name of each function twice on each line - is it possible to somehow automate this with Rollup.js? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use "as" as acronym for all imports

```js
import * as util from './util';
export {util};
```